# CakePHP 3 - Query COUNT() returning incorrect number

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a fairly complex query, which includes a SQL count in a subquery join.

The problem is Cake's query builder returns a count of 23, but I know this is incorrect. So I debugged the SQL query it built, and ran it directly in MySQL. The strange thing is the raw SQL being generated by Cake is correct and it returns a count of 1 when I run it, which is also correct.

I am hesitant to call this a bug with the query builder, but it seems like the way Cake is interpreting the SQL result is wrong somehow. I can't see what is wrong here, or how this is possible.

I have stripped down the query here to the very basics which are causing the issue.

**Query object**

This is what is being generated by the query builder. The SQL is correct.

```
object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
    'sql' => 'SELECT Orders.order_id AS `Orders__order_id`, all_orders.total AS `Customers__orders_placed`, Customers.id AS `Customers__id`, Customers.email AS `Customers__email`, FROM orders Orders LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.customer_id AS `T__customer_id`, COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM orders T GROUP BY customer_id ) all_orders ON all_orders.T__customer_id = :c0 LEFT JOIN customers Customers ON Customers.id = (Orders.customer_id) WHERE Orders.order_id = :c1',
    'params' => [
        ':c0' => [
            'value' => 'Orders.customer_id',
            'type' => null,
            'placeholder' => 'c0'
        ],
        ':c1' => [
            'value' => '12345',
            'type' => 'string',
            'placeholder' => 'c1'
        ]
    ],

    // ...
```

**Cake's generated SQL (formatted for readability)**

```
SELECT
    Orders.order_id AS `Orders__order_id`,
    all_orders.total AS `Customers__orders_placed`,
    Customers.id AS `Customers__id`,
    Customers.email AS `Customers__email`,

FROM orders Orders

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T.customer_id AS `T__customer_id`,
    COUNT(*) AS `total`
    FROM orders T
    GROUP BY customer_id
) all_orders ON all_orders.T__customer_id = :c0

LEFT JOIN customers Customers ON Customers.id = (Orders.customer_id)

WHERE Orders.order_id = :c1
```

**Query builder result**

Note that `customer->orders_placed` = 23

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Order) {

    'order_id' => '12345',
    'customer' => object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {

        'orders_placed' => '23',
        'id' => (int) 34727,
        'email' => 'xxxxx@example.com',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Customers'

    },
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Orders'

}
```

**If I run the query myself in MySQL**

The only thing I change from Cake's SQL is I fill in the parameters for `:c0` and `:c1`.

```
SELECT
    Orders.order_id AS `Orders__order_id`,
    all_orders.total AS `Customers__orders_placed`,
    Customers.id AS `Customers__id`,
    Customers.email AS `Customers__email`

FROM orders Orders

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T.customer_id AS `T__customer_id`,
    COUNT(*) AS `total`
    FROM orders T
    GROUP BY customer_id
) all_orders ON all_orders.T__customer_id = Orders.customer_id

LEFT JOIN customers Customers ON Customers.id = (Orders.customer_id)

WHERE Orders.order_id = 12345
```

Then when I run it in MySQL, this is the result:

```
Orders__order_id | Customers__orders_placed | Customers__id | Customers__email
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345            | 1                        | 34727         | xxxxx@example.com
```

**How can the count be different when I'm literally copy/pasting the SQL generated by Cake?**

Cake version is 3.3.16

Comment: You are binding an identifier / a column name (`Orders.customer_id`), I'm mildly sure that the value will be inserted as a string literal.

Comment: You're selecting non-aggregated columns in your join subquery which is using a `GROUP BY` on the `customer_id` only. As soon as you try to run this on a version of MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` it's going to throw a SQL exception.

Comment: @cgTag There's one aggregated column, and one column that is named in the `GROUP BY` clause, that should work fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ndm you can only SELECT what is in the GROUP BY columns. Older versions of MySQL are the only SQL driver that allow it, but newer versions are SQL97 complainant. You can disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP` to which MySQL states the results of non-aggregated columns is `undefined`.

Comment: @cgTag And there's also functionally dependent columns, I know... my point is just that I fail to see where something is being selected that would violate the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode rules, as mentioned, there's only two columns being selected, one is named in the `GROUP BY` clause, and one is an aggregate result, hence it shouldn't violate the rules.

Comment: @ndm well, I don't know. I did try it with MySQL 5.7.19 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled, and it fails. From what I understand you basically can only select from the group by. `COUNT(*)` isn't in the group by so it fails.

Comment: @cgTag `COUNT()` is an aggregate function, that should be fine. Maybe you're confused by the `*`? The query works for me on MySQL 5.7.20 with with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled.

Comment: I think mdm is right: try and replace `all_orders.T__customer_id = Orders.customer_id` with `all_orders.T__customer_id = 'Orders.customer_id'` directly in mysql and see what happens.

Comment: @ndm But I also tried explicitly specifying the type of the customer ID as integer using the third parameter of the `leftJoin()` method. Same result. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @cgTag Even if a full GROUP BY violation was causing the issue, how would it be that the query is working and returning different numbers?

Comment: You cannot bind identifiers, no matter what type you specify. Please show the code that generates the query if you need further help with that.

Comment: @ndm You were correct. I managed to get it working by providing the join condition as a single string, rather than an associative array, to prevent it from interpreting it as a string literal.

Comment: You can use `new IdentifierExpression('Orders.customer_id')` instead of a string when you need to reference a column.

Comment: @cgTag Great, thanks.